# Сканирование устройств BLE на телефоне Samsung

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth-le

Всем привет. На руках имеются:

1. STEVAL-IDB011V1 (отладочная плата), на борту СНК BLUENRG-355MC;
2. Собранная плата с BLUENRG-355MC и датчиками;
3. Телефоны Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) и Galaxy M31.

Для отладочной платы и собранной платы написана прошивка (загружена в обе платы), с использованием библиотеки от STM BlueNRG-LP. На Андройд разработано приложение с использованием библиотеки Blessed ([тык](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android)).

Подключение Android к отладочной плате идёт на ура, всё прекрасно работает. Проверено на Samsung и других телефонах (Xiaomi, LG, Pixel).
Залил ту же самую прошивку в собранную плату. Работает также прекрасно со всеми телефонами, подключается ко всем, кроме Samsung'а, который видит только отладочную плату.

Устройство в центральной роли - телефон, плата - периферия.

Что делал:

- проверял плату на неисправности. Всё нормально работает. По коду каждый уголок с отладчиком прошёл. Обнаруживается другими устройствами отлично, пакет не кривой;
- Проверял приложение Android. Находит все устройства вокруг, кроме моей разработки. Также менял библиотеку на стандартный Android BLE, не помогло;
- На Samsung пытался отловить сниффером пакеты, которые посылает плата, но ловятся только пакеты от отладочной платы, другой как-будто и нет. На других телефонах ловится всё отлично от обеих плат;
- Поиск устройства из меню стандартного Bluetooth. Samsung видит только отладку, остальные телефоны видят обе платы;
- Чистил все кэши на телефоне.

Все разрешения есть, местоположение активно и разрешено. Телефоны на Android 10 и 11.

Подскажите, куда можно копать дальше?

Comment: а нет ли у блютуса какого-либо "региона", как это есть у wifi. И поэтому не видит.

Comment: Нет, такого нету.